# Why I am the raid configuration tool is now allowing me to create RAID 10?

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, dell-poweredge, raid10

I have an older dell power edge 6800 server. I have upgraded it a bit and I want to utilize it. So I wadded some ram and some drives.

it currently has 12 drives. 
2 @ (146gb)
10 @ (300 gb)

I configured the first 2 drives RAID 1 "mirror" for the OS.
And then 2 of the 10 drives are another RAID 1.
Then the last 8 drives I want to configure them RAID 10. But the tool is only giving me 2 raid options 1 and 5 but not 10.

I am not sure why. Is there a limitation in the utility? If so, how can I fix that? 
What do I need in order to configure those 8 drives to Raid 10.

Thanks

Comment: Which RAID configuration tool?  For that matter, which RAID controller, and which version?

Comment: Hi, the bios configuration tool is "Bios Config utility is U827  jan 21, 2005" and the raid controller "H435 dated April 23  2008" and the raid.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, based on the sever model and the dates you gave in the comments, the RAID controller you have is a Perc 4/DC or Perc 4e/Di RAID card.  They're pretty old, and accordingly, don't have the fancy automatic options you're accustomed to in newer software, like the automagical *put-these-drives-in-RAID-10*" configuration option, so you have to do it manually.

[RAID 10 is a nested RAID level, which is to say it is a stripe of mirrors - groups of RAID 1 arrays that are then striped together into one larger array](https://serverfault.com/q/339128/118258).  In your case, if you want to put these 8 drives into a single RAID 10 array, you will need to first create 4 RAID 1 arrays, and then apply a RAID 0 array onto all four RAID 1 arrays.

To do this in your particular software, you would use the span option and select all four of the RAID 1 arrays you would have just created.  [From Dell's Perc 4 Easy Configuration guide](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ebrecht/servers/docs/PowerEdge-2600/en/Perc4scdc/UG/bios.htm):

> PERC 4 supports spanning of RAID 1 and 5 arrays. You can span two or more contiguous RAID 1 logical drives into a RAID 10 array, and two or more contiguous RAID 5 logical drives into a RAID 50 array. You need at least two hard drives in two separate RAID 1 arrays to create a RAID 10 array and at least three hard drives in two separate RAID 5 arrays to create a RAID 50 array.
>
> For two arrays to be spanned, they must have the same stripe width (they must contain the same number of physical drives) and must be consecutively numbered.
>
> For example, assuming array 2 contains four hard drives, it can be spanned only with array 1 and/or array 3, and only if arrays 1 and 3 also contain four hard drives. If the two criteria for spanning are met, PERC 4 automatically allows spanning. If the criteria are not met, the Span setting makes no difference for the current logical drive.

Comment: Thank a lot for this answer. I am following your logic. As I am in the middle of trying to construct the RAID 10 manually as your suggestion. The only thing that I am not sure on how to do is how can I select all 4 spans "raid 1 spans" and make them a RAID 0. I don't see an option to allow me to do that. Do you know the step that I should follow? What I did is go to new configuration and then I selected 2 disks at a time and made them RAID 1 but now, I am stuck and I am not sure how to select the span itself to convert it to raid 0. do I initialize the drives first and then reconstruct again?

Comment: @Mike Unfortunately, I don't have access to a PERC 4 card, and my memory's foggy on exactly how it works, so I don't think I can be of any more assistance. :(  Sorry.